# Express JS Router Middleware - Body Parser - req.body has hyphen

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am receiving parsed emails from Mailgun that are posted via their API to a URL end point I set up. The URL that receives the HTTP posts is an Expressjs Route to MongoDB using body parser middleware. I have the http post to the route working fine to MongoDB for simple text keys like 'sender', however I have an issue with the format of some of the message parameters containing hyphens. For instance "body-plain". Express throws an error if I include the a parameter of "req.body.body-plain". Does anyone have a work around?

I would prefer not to regex the entire string.

Here is an example of the email response being posted:

```
recipient: 'postmaster@appmail.sisdaf.com',
  sender: 'kevsdaf@mail.com',
  subject: 'tewsgs',
  from: 'Kevin Psdit <kesdfit@gmail.com>',
  'X-Envelope-From': '<kasdftit@gmail.com>',
'body-plain': 'this is a test\r\n',
  Received: 
   [ 'from mail-qk0-f179.google.com (mail-qk0-f179.google.com         [209.85.220.179]) by mxa.mailgun.org with ESMTP id 556bfda1.7f7658358ef0-    in01; Mon, 01 Jun 2015 06:37:21 -0000 (UTC)',
 'by qkx62 with SMTP id 62so79143349qkx.3 for <postmaster@appmail.simadsftrade.com>; Sun, 31 May 2015 23:37:21 -0700 (PDT)',
 'by 10.140.18.241 with HTTP; Sun, 31 May 2015 23:37:21 -0700 (PDT)' ],
  'Dkim-Signature': 'v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=gmail.com;     s=20120113; h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;   cdx2K5lDwCjwcy0S6407m6/q9tAnFIltsT48O1nCACzQ4RQQYiXa VuiA==',
 'Mime-Version': '1.0',
  'X-Received': 'by 10.55.23.130 with SMTP id    2mr35323631qkx.33.1433140641295; Sun, 31 May 2015 23:37:21 -0700 (PDT
)',Date: 'Sun, 31 May 2015 23:37:21 -0700'
```

Here is the Express route:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
 var Email = mongoose.model('Email');

module.exports = function(router) {

router.route('/emails')
  //creates a new email
  .post(function(req, res){
      var email = new Email();

//THESE WORK
  email.recipient = req.body.recipient;
  email.sender = req.body.sender;
  email.from = req.body.from;
  email.subject = req.body.subject;
  email.timestamp = req.body.timestamp;
  email.token = req.body.token;
  email.signature = req.body.signature;

//THESE DO NOT WORK BECAUSE OF HYPHEN IN NAME
  email.body_plain = req.body.body-plain;
  email.stripped_text = req.body.stripped-text;
  email.stripped_signature = req.body.stripped-signature;
  email.body_html = req.body.body-html;
  email.stripped_html = req.body.stripped-html;
  email.attachment_count = req.body.attachment-count;
  email.attachment_x = req.body.attachment-x;
  email.message_headers = req.body.message-headers;
  email.content_id_map = req.body.content-id-map;      

email.save(function(err, email) {
  if (err){
    return res.send(500, err);
  }
  return res.json(email);
});
  })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The workaround is to use bracket notation, that way you can access keys that have characters that aren't valid in dot notation

```
req.body['body-plain']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Extra Details:** If you are using a **mongoose** model and it also has hyphen then you do is this way.

Suppose this is how your mongoose model looks like, *note the properties with hyphens in their names*:

```
const augmentedWritingTextSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  'profile-id': {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  'profile-type': {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  'company-wide-visibility': {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Then your document should look like this when using the *mongoose model*:

```
  augmentedWritingTextDocument = new AugmentedWritingText({
      text: reqObj.text,
      name: reqObj.name,
      'profile-id': reqObj['profile-id'],
      'profile-type': reqObj['profile-type'],
      'company-wide-visibility': reqObj['company-wide-visibility'],
    });
```